# Can't understand how Dir iterates through the next directory when it is used within a loop

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I've created a macro to get all the folder names containing movies that starts with `The` from D drive. The macro is doing fine. What I can't understand is how this `filepath = Dir` iterates through the next directory as I didn't use any index or such.

```
Sub GetMovieNames()
    Dim filepath$

    filepath = Dir("D:\Movies\The*", vbDirectory)
    
    Do While filepath <> ""
        Debug.Print filepath
        filepath = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

It looks at first glance that the variable `filepath` always gets the same `Dir` every time the loop runs.

> How Dir function goes for the next directory even when there is no index in it?

Comment: Dir is an object which holds state, the state being the parameters you supply when you first call it.  For subsequent calls, if you don't provide any new state it will use its internal state to workout which directory to give you next, until it runs out of valid names when it will return an empty string.

Comment: If you want to see examples in other languages look up the term 'Iterator'

Comment: This is how it looks usual `For Each filepath In Dir: Debug.Print filepath: Next filepath`

Answer (score 0):

Besides Dir usage, this will provide a folder / subfolder list containg "Movies":

```
' List of subfolders
' Needs to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference to your file
Sub SubFoldersInfo(ByVal pFolder As String, ByRef pColFolders As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal pMe As Boolean)
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFolder, oSubFolder As Folder
    
    sFolder = IIf(Right(pFolder, 1) <> "\", pFolder & "\", pFolder)
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
    If pMe Then
        pColFolders.Add oFolder
    End If
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        pColFolders.Add oSubFolder
        SubFoldersInfo oSubFolder.Path, pColFolders, False
    Next
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TestMe()
    Dim colFolders As New Collection, sFolderPath As Variant
    SubFoldersInfo "D:\", colFolders, True
    For Each sFolderPath In colFolders
        If InStr(1, sFolderPath.Path, "Movies") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print sFolderPath.ShortName & " : "; sFolderPath.Path
        End If
    Next sFolderPath
End Sub
```

You can change SubFoldersInfo sub by adding a filter parameter, instead of filtering results in TestMe().